# What is the best way to store and retrieve a friend's list on Firebase (Swift)

Tags: database, swift, firebase, social-networking

Suppose we have this data

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Hillary"
    friends
      uid_1: true
      uid_2: true
  uid_1
    name: "Kato"
  uid_2
    name: "Bill"
```

Using Swift, how can I retrieve the friends list as an array?

I've thought of using a 'for' loop that runs through the users dictionary and matches the friends, but that would repeat the loop many times. (Not efficient?)

I've also thought of just making a loop that go to the path of the friend's uid and gets it's value from the server.

```
ref.child("users/uid_1")).observeSingleEventOfType.... etc.
```

I expect 2 returned objects one containing "name": "Kato" [String: String] and the other containing "name": "Bill"
(sounds like a much less client-intensive method, however that uses significantly more server calls)

Although I thank you for giving me your valuable time, I request that you include real code in your answers if possible.

Comment: That works. You could also use a cache of users [like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/uoe5yt8x/).

Comment: Which of the two is better? I expect the second one as the number of users becomes huge.

Comment: The number of users won't really be a factor here. You can only view so many records on the client at a time and you are only fetching ones that are viewed.

Comment: Do you mind giving me some sample code/ pseudocode?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the link?

Comment: I don't see how you're filtering the users list using a list of ids (the friends list) in the link.